# static variable with BufWriter in Rust

Tags: rust

I would like to get a global variable with BufWriter.

This code is executed without errors, but writing to the file is not carried out:

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref WRITER: Mutex<BufWriter<File>> = {
        let file = File::create("test.bin").unwrap();
        BufWriter::new(file).into()
    }
}
WRITER.lock().unwrap().write_all(&vec![1, 2, 3, 4]).unwrap();
```

Comment: Its buffering the write. You need to call `flush`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things come into play:

- A `BufWriter` absorbes writes in its internal buffer before handing them to the operating system until either

  - Its buffer is full
  - It has `flush` called
  - It gets `Drop`ped
- `lazy_static` items are never Dropped

So, to make your code work, you must do something like

```
let mut writer = WRITER.lock().unwrap();
writer.write_all(&vec![1, 2, 3, 4]).unwrap();
writer.flush().unwrap();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6328bad09b0506535544512500040f48) (with one minor syntax error fixed)

Alternatively:

- You construct the `BufWriter` in your `main` function and hand a reference to it through all method calls.
- A bit dirty, but you could call `flush` from a [`dtor`](https://docs.rs/ctor/latest/ctor/).

Comment: "flush()" method really helped. Thank you!